# Java Applet not working?

Tags: java, applet

I tried uploading my applet html and my .class but it isn't working? The link is: http://monaiz.net/holiday/holidayproject.html

I put the `holidayproject.class` in the same location

This is my applet code:

```
<APPLET CODE = "holidayproject.class" WIDTH=1000 HEIGHT=650>
</APPLET>
```

Comment: *"did not work?"*  Perhaps it is sleepy, or lazy.  If neither of those is the case, there should be errors or exceptions in the Java console.  What is the output in the console?

Comment: Webpage and applet not longer available.

Answer (score 0):

Some Google fodder for you.

---

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: holidayproject : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: holidayproject : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Comment: You're not running 1.7 in your browser? (Personally, I am not intending to install 7 for some time, early versions seem to have bugs in APIs of close interest to me.)

Comment: No, I'm running whatever IT gives me :) I could, I suppose, but in cases like this, it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: From that output, the first thing I'd recommend is to compile the code with the [cross-compilation options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options) to specify the earliest JRE that can run the code.